# How to change Apache's hardcoded Error pages?

Tags: apache, apache2

How to change Apache's hard coded Error pages, instead of using `ErrorDocument` directive. Because, I do not want to place the `ErrorDocument` file inside the htdocs folder, as it creates some issues when the user visits the error page itself. Such as the environment variable `REDIRECT_URL` not working, and stuff like that. I have tried to find stuff in the apache directory, but no luck, i cannot find anything that can be modified to change the hardcoded error pages itself. Is there a way at all to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit them if you install apache from source, download the source from httpd.apache.org/download.cgi, and you can find the contents of the files using `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'texttofind'` if using linux. And modify them to your needs (carefully of course), and you can compile it and use it.

But, I would suggest you to just stick with the `ErrorDocument` directive, which is much simpler.

Happy Cod3ing.

Comment: Hmm... seems complicated... I will try it and come back... Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found a file that contains some of the stuff. I will accept your answer until i get any easier answers.